# MultipartFile not in "@RequestParam Map<String, Object> requestParams" variable

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc

So I'm currently building a Multipart-Fileupload with Spring. I want to create my Controller as generic as it can be to enable a good start for my own modulized-controller-application. That's why I'm working with `@RequestParam Map<String, Object> requestParams`. So my dummy function looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(path = "uploadtest", method = POST, consumes = MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE)
    public String test(@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
                       @RequestParam Map<String, Object> requestParams) {
        return "/[...]";
    }
```

Now when I post a file, I would asume, that it would be available through the `file`-variable (works, ok.) and through `requestParams.get("file")` (doesn't work).

So here is my question:

Is this intendet to work like this, or is there just no multipart-support enabled for the general `@RequestParams` annotation (=Bug/Feature?).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A multipart request consist of several parts. In case of `multipart/form-data` the first part is supposed to consist of parameter / value pairs that are also available as `@RequestParam`. The other parts are the files.

When you have `@RequestParam MultipartFile file` Spring knows that you want the  **part** that is associated with the `file` parameter. Since the file is a part you can also use `@RequestPart("file") MultipartFile file`.

Keep in mind that request parameters are Strings. So `Map<String, Object>` is basically the same as `Map<String, String>`. Therefore `requestParams.get("file")` will give you a String value of the `file` parameter from the first part of the request.

*"I want to create my Controller as generic as it can be"* You rather want it as specific as it can be. If you want to keep things generic, then don't use controllers in the first place.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. So when I sum it up the `@RequestParam` working for files is so to say a feature of Spring. This would make sence, but fooles the programmer not knowing these facts :)

Answer (score 2):

I founded greate solution to get file map as **Map<String, MultipartFile> fileMap**.
You should use : **multiRequest.getFileMap();** from object HttpServletRequest.

```
    @PostMapping(consumes = {MULTIPART_FORM_DATA_VALUE})
    ResponseEntity<String> createDocument(@RequestParam Map<String, String> allParams, HttpServletRequest request)

Map<String, MultipartFile> fileMap = new HashMap<String, MultipartFile>();
if (request instanceof MultipartHttpServletRequest) {
    MultipartHttpServletRequest multiRequest = (MultipartHttpServletRequest) request;
    fileMap = multiRequest.getFileMap();
}
```